# How can i add column name in list generic?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

```
 class MyExcelSheets
    {
        public List MyColumnNames { get; set; }
    }
```

how can i add Excel data's column name in "List MyColumnNames ". it returns to me **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

i want to use above class in:

```
     myexcelSheet = new MyExcelSheets();
                myexcelSheet.MyColumnNames = new MyExcelSheets().MyColumnNames;
                foreach (DataColumn col in dTable.Columns)
                  myexcelSheet.MyColumnNames.Add(col.ColumnName.ToString());
```

How can i solve it?

Error: NullReferenceException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Code `myexcelSheet.MyColumnNames = new MyExcelSheets().MyColumnNames;` only obtains the reference to the property , but it doesnt instantiate that.

Adding the code

```
this. MyColumnNames = new List<string>;
```

in a static constructor will solve the issue , as this part of the code will be called by the run time and we dont have to worry about instantiating state transfer objects (as it is in this case)

E.g.,

```
static MyExcelSheets(){this. MyColumnNames = new List<string>; }
```

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `public List MyColumnNames { get; set; }` is actually declared as `public List<string> MyColumnNames { get; set; }`

The row:

```
myexcelSheet.MyColumnNames = new MyExcelSheets().MyColumnNames;
```

Should be:

```
 myexcelSheet.MyColumnNames = new List<string>;
```

Though it would normally be better to do this in a constructor or something.